# show limit fields on autoForm

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema, quickform

I have this schema:

```
AdsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title"
  },
  _cityId: {
    type: String,
    label: "City ID"
  },
  _categoryId: {
    type: String,
    label: "Category ID"
  },
  insertedDateTime: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Inserted Date Time",
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return new Date();
      } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
      } else {
        this.unset();  // Prevent user from supplying their own value
      }
    }
  },
  insertedBy: {
    type: String,
    label: "Inserted By"
    defalutValue: Meteor.user().username
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Price"
  },
  image: {
    type: Object,
    label: "Image",
    optional: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    label: "Email"
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    label: "Phone Number",
    optional: true
  },
  desc: {
    type: String,
    label: "Description",
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        type: "textarea",
        rows: 10
      }
    }
  },
  quickOrNot: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Quick Or Not",
  }
});
```

I use quickForm for insert to mongoDB, whit following code:

```
{{> quickForm schema="AdsSchema" collection="Ads" id="insBaseAds" type="insert"}}
```

and autoForm generate for me a form with all of schema's fields.

but I want only limit fields to show to user on autform, for example these fields:

```
title, price, image, email, phoneNumber, desc
```

and I fill some fields my self, for example these fields:

```
_cityId: "test",
_categoryId: "test",
insertBy: "test"
```

how can I use quickForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use afQuickfields

```
{{>afQuickFields  fields="title, price, image, email, phoneNumber, desc"}}
```

else you can use type 'hidden' in schema

```
_cityId: {
type: String,
label: "City ID",
autoform:{
  type:"hidden"
  } 
}
```

Comment: it's OK, but how I can initialize some fields?

Comment: If you are asking exactly on how to assign value to fields , we have `defaultValue` and `autoValue` fields to assign value.`defaultvalue` is used to assign same value to all the documents irrespective of any other conditions,where as `autoValue` helps you to add value conditionally